# React with custom routing (on Symfony backend)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony, react-router

Just started new React project (still beginner in React) and I have to deal with new problem concerning routing.

Website is based on Symfony backend and there React used on front. When launching page, I have to go to URL where slug is required and it's controlled by Symfony routing and it's OK:

```
//domain.com/slug
```

But then I have react app where everything happens on single page. On this single page I have container in which I have to switch components depending on user actions (like simple clicking links). Not whole page is reloading, only components container part. It's simple as this part of MainPage component (root):

```
<header>some header</header>
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="switch-components-inside">
        <ComponentsWrapper page={this.state.subPage} />
    </div>
</div>
<footer>footer!</footer>
```

And to be honest I am confused, because I have no idea how to use react-router to construct such structure. Maybe I should do url modifications by my own? I want to be able to use URLs like this (can be with hash after slug of course), but all of them should direct to same component (MainPage) and only part of site should load different component.

```
//domain.com/slug#/news
//domain.com/slug#/news/some-news
//domain.com/slug#/authors
//domain.com/slug#/authors/some-author
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `react-router`'s [`HashRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) for hash-based routing.

> A `<Router>` that uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e.
>   window.location.hash) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE: Hash history does not support location.key or
>   location.state. In previous versions we attempted to shim the behavior
>   but there were edge-cases we couldn't solve. Any code or plugin that
>   needs this behavior won't work. As this technique is only intended to
>   support legacy browsers, we encourage you to configure your server to
>   work with  instead.

So in your case you might have:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <header>some header</header>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/news" component={NewsComponent}/>
            <Route path="/authors" component={AuthorsComponent}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <footer>footer!</footer>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  )
};
```

Based on the IMPORTANT NOTE, though, it would be better to configure your backend to ignore routes nested under the `//domain.com/slug` and instead use `<BrowserRouter basename="/slug">`